# How to make an array in Java read only?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Java unmodifiable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737769/java-unmodifiable-array)
>   [Immutable array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java)

How do I make an array read only so that the elements inside it can only be read but cannot be modified,added or deleted. need to do this in JAVA. Please help. I think merely the use of final keyword wont help.Need to do something more than that at the code level. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is you can't -- final will only guarantee you that the reference to the array itself won't be changed. You can do this with a List though, as the Collections class provides a method for creating a List that cannot be modified (Collections.unmodifiableList) -- that is only if you can change your application to use List rather than array.

Comment: thanks Liv for your answer...Basically I am trying to implement ArrayList using array.So as in Collections we have this method unmodifiableList, how can I implement the same ArrayList which I have implemented using array as readonly. I hope I am able to make the question clear now.