# Java array of constants

Tags: java, arrays, enums

How is it possible to declare and initialize an array of constants in Java, without using `enums` ?

```
static final Type[] arrayOfConstants = new Type[10]; // not an array of constants
```

Comment: You mean ensure the values of the array cannot be changed? You will need to encapsulate the array in an object that prevents mutation but allows access by index via getter method

Comment: I mean the array components be constants i.e. a[0] be a constant variable like this public static final int SIZE = 10;

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want to give the array indexes names?

Comment: @Vince Emigh Your answer before makes sense to me.

Comment: What answer? The only answer I have is [down below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33095247/2398375), which you can kindly choose as accepted answer if it helped with your issue :) Unless you're referring to my comment, which in that case my answer includes that info (with examples), and you should check it out

Comment: I think there are Immutable Collections in java, but not arrays unfortunately

Answer (score 18):

If you want to create an immutable array, no, you cannot. All arrays in Java are mutable.

If you just want to predefine the array in your class, you can do it:

```
private static final int[] MY_ARRAY = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Here we created a predefined array `MY_ARRAY` of length 5, so `MY_ARRAY[0]` is `10` and so on. Be careful though as even the `MY_ARRAY` field is declared final, this does not mean that array elements could not be changed. Thus it's better not to expose such array to public via `public` or `protected` modifier.

Comment: No this is not an array of constants, this is a constant array. i mean the components of the array be constants not the array itself

Comment: @AthanasiosV., please reread the very first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Yes your statement is absolutely right sorry for me quick response

Comment: ...except for zero-length arrays, which are safely immutable.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to modify the values, and you also just want to access the members of the collection without wanting random access, a very simple solution instead of having a constant array, have a final immutable list:

```
static final ImmutableList<Type> arrayOfConstants = ImmutableList.of(t1, t2, t3);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I mean the array components be constants i.e. a[0] be a constant variable like this public static final int SIZE = 10;

You cannot give array indexes names.

You could initialize an array using the values of pre-existing constants:

```
public static final int SIZE = 10;

public static final int[] CONSTANTS = { SIZE };
```

---

Keep in mind that although an array is declared `final`, it's values may still be changed. `final` only ensures you cannot re-assign the array variable, so you will want to encapsulate the array to prevent mutation:

```
final class Constants {
    public static final int SIZE = 10;

    private static final int[] CONSTANTS = { SIZE };

    public static int getConstant(int index) {
       return CONSTANTS[index];
    }
}
```

If you would like to loop, I suggest returning a [deep-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of the array.

Comment: The question wasn't "how do I give array indices names", it was "how do I make an array of constants, this thing shows what I mean by constant". Your answer says "you can't do this unrelated thing, oh and by the way you should keep in mind this caveat which is literally the entire center of your question".

Answer (score 1):

if final is used with objects you cannot change the reference of that object but  changing the value is perfectly fine.Array is an object in java and if you want object value should not be changed, once created, then you will have to make object immutable and primitive array cannot be made immutable in java.

```
    final int [] finalArr={5,6,8};

     System.out.println("Value at index 0 is "+finalArr[0]);    
      //output : Value at index 0 is 5

      //perfectly fine
      finalArr[0]=41;

     System.out.println("Changed value at index 0 is "+finalArr[0]);
    //Changed value at index 0 is 41

     int[] anotherArr={7,9,6};
     // finalArr=anotherArr;
     //error : cannot assign a value to final variable finalArr
```

For more on immutable array you can refer to these links:

[Immutable array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java)

[Is there any way to make an ordinary array immutable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122974/is-there-any-way-to-make-an-ordinary-array-immutable-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

-If you know the values before-hand, initialize the array values and mark that array as `final`.

-If you don't know the values initially then write public getter/setters methods and declare the array as `private`. Write logic in setter method to discard changes once done on a particular element (or throw an exception upon multiple changes to the same element)

Answer (score 0):

Its'been a while this post is open
I am surprised, why any one would not think of

```
public static final List<LanguageModel> GenderDataSource = new ArrayList<GenderModel>(){{
    add(new LanguageModel("0", "English"));
    add(new LanguageModel("1", "Hindi"));
    add(new LanguageModel("1", "Tamil"));
};};
```

Where **LanguageModel** simply contains two properties Id and Title or use whatever your model class of generic Type could be.

Should work great as constant.

-- N Baua

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post and it made me think about something I did for a chess playing application.

Maybe you just want a group of constants that are sons of another constant. I mean, if you make a final class named as your "array", and inside it you describe several constants, you'll be able to access it via MyClass.MYARRAY.MYCONSTANT.

The code would be:

```
abstract class Figure {
    public static final class WEIGHT{
        public static final int PAWN = 1;
        public static final int KNIGHT = 3;
        public static final int BISHOP = 3;
        public static final int ROCK = 5;
        public static final int QUEEN = 10;
        public static final int KING = 1000;
    }
}

public class Pawn extends Figure{
    public static final int weight = Figure.WEIGHT.PAWN;
}
```

I don't know if it is the best way for doing it. I don't either know if it's the worst way. But I think it answers your question and gives you a solution.