# How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<Integer>) from array (int[]) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

I have seen the question: [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

However when I try that solution with following code, it doesn't quite work in all the cases:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class ToArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this works
        String[] elements = new String[] { "Ryan", "Julie", "Bob" };
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(elements));
        System.out.println(list);

        // this works
        List<Integer> intList = null;
        intList = Arrays.asList(3, 5);
        System.out.println(intList);

        int[] intArray = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        // this doesn't work!
        intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
        System.out.println(intList);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the code `intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));` compile just fine?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I found several reasons for this compilation errors: 1. Java doesn't autobox primitive arrays. 2. Varargs are complicated to correctly use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java/2926653#2926653

Comment: +1 this is a good question. I recommend anyone reading it to read all the answers, they all add important info.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem in

```
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

is that `int[]` is considered as a single `Object` instance since a primitive array extends from `Object`. This would work if you have `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` since now you're sending an array of `Object`.

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1 };
//now you're sending a Object array
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

From your comment: if you want to still use an `int[]` (or another primitive type array) as main data, then you need to create an additional array with the wrapper class. For this example:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 0, 1 };
Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[intArray.length];
int i = 0;
for(int intValue : intArray) {
    integerArray[i++] = intValue;
}
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integerArray));
```

But since you're already using a `for` loop, I wouldn't mind using a temp wrapper class array, just add your items directly into the list:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 0, 1 };
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int intValue : intArray) {
    intList.add(intValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I convert a primitive array to boxed array instead of creating a new one ( ex. not using a loop )? I am only looking forward to a compact piece of code that I can use.

Answer (score 18):

With Java 8 you can do it in one line:

```
        
int[] intArr = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11};  
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(intArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());  
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 11):

The issue is about [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Java automatically converts `int` to `Integer` automatically. But Java **cannot convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`**. Hence the reason.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

`asList` is defined as above. It expects a vararg of type `T`. i.e. it can take an array of objects of type `T`. In your case because Java cannot convert `int[]` to `Integer[]`, hence it takes type `T` as `int[]` rather than `Integer` as desired. Hence you get a list of type `List<int[]`. You will have to manually convert it into `Integer[]` from `int[]`.

There is an excellent item in the book [*Effective Java*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34927404-effective-java) by [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) where he explains the pitfalls of [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). This is one of them.

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work because you're using an `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`. Try this:

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1 };
// this should work now
intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

Answer (score 3):

Collection wants Objects and primitives don't derive from Object. so `Integer` allow but `int` is not allow.

So you have to use wrapper class `Integer` instead of `int` which is primitive type.

**Just example:**

```
 Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1 };
 intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

The below provides an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, j = 0;

        Integer[] StandArr = new Integer[10];
        for (i = 0; i < StandArr.length; i++) {
            StandArr[i] = i * 3;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < StandArr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(StandArr[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(StandArr));
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```