# Argument mismatch when trying to construct HashSet<Integer> from list — why?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, set

So, I have been doing an online code problem on this website called Codewars and I'm having some problem with my code. When I was using the set interface, it gave me an error:

```
/workspace/java/src/FindOdd.java:16: error: no suitable constructor found for HashSet(List<int[]>)
    Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
                        ^
    constructor HashSet.HashSet(Collection<? extends Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
          inferred: int[]
          upper bound(s): Integer,Object)
    constructor HashSet.HashSet(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to int)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)
Note: /workspace/java/src/FindOdd.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

(by the way, my code isn't finished, tell me if I have to finish it first or not)

this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FindOdd {
  public static int findIt(int[] arr) {
    LinkedHashMap apearanceCount = new LinkedHashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(apearanceCount.containsKey(arr[i])){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(apearanceCount.get(arr[i]).toString()) + 1;
        apearanceCount.put(arr[i], amount);
      } else {
        apearanceCount.put(arr[i], 1);
      }
    }

    Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
  }
}
```

Please help me!

(for people who think this is a duplicate, from what I know, arrays converting to sets isn't the same as converting arrays to lists. If I am wrong, answer in the comments. ;) )

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr)` is returning an instance of `List<int[]>` - this is the problem with primitives :/

Comment: Arrays.as List(arr) accepts a type array, which means all elements used need to be Object types rather than primitives.
Use an Integer array instead of int (primitive type):

Integer[] arr; it will work like charm

public static boolean printer(Integer arr[], int n)
{
Set<Integer> set = new Hash Set<Integer>(Arrays.as List(arr));

Comment: import java.util.*;

public class FindOdd {
  public static int findIt(Integer[] arr) {
    LinkedHashMap apearanceCount = new LinkedHashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(apearanceCount.containsKey(arr[i])){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(apearanceCount.get(arr[i]).toString()) + 1;
        apearanceCount.put(arr[i], amount);
      } else {
        apearanceCount.put(arr[i], 1);
      }
    }

    Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
  }
}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error is saying the `HashSet` class doesn't have a constructor that takes the *interface* `List`. It does, however, have a constructor for the `Collection` interface. So try `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr))`.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr))` just results in a `ArrayList<int[]>` list, which is the same as `Arrays.asList` :/ - You need to convert the `int` values to `Integer`, either through a second array or directly yo the map/list

Comment: Doesn't java auto box the int to and Integer?

Comment: @SamOrozco For single values, yes, but not for entire arrays.

Comment: @SamOrozco `int[]` isn't a primitive, it's a "special" type of object, so, no, auto boxing won't help here

Comment: Note that `List extends Collection`.

Comment: Sry guys, I'm just a ten year old learning coding and I don't exactly understand the things your are talking about. well, I guess I understand some, int[], I guess, Arraylists, kinda. It's just that, can you guys explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: Basically @ChickenSoup439 I mislead you and didn't test my code example before I posted it as the answer. You will find the answer of your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520964/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistinteger-from-array-int-in-java