# Can i define an final String[][] with some other final String[]s?

Tags: java

i defined some final String arrays and initial them at another place, now i want to make it easier to traverse them, so maybe i need to put them in a final String[][] ,

```
  private static final String[] a,b,c,d;
  private static final String[][] all = {a,b,c,d};
```

but it give me errors

```
The blank final field a may not have been initialized
```

now i know the final variable should be assigned before used but i have no idea to solve my problem, is there any way to traverse a,b,c,d easier than the following code?

```
  for(String s : a){};
  for(String s : b){};
  ...
```

BTW i want to assign by traversing them

Comment: Where do you currently initialize the `String[]` variables?

Comment: i initialize them in constructor

Comment: You initialise `static` variables in a constructor?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth orz...it seems wrong..now i initial them in a static block, there are still errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know the size of `a` through `d`, you can initialize them when you declare them:

```
private static final String[] a = new String[YOUR_VALUE_HERE], 
                              b = new String[YOUR_VALUE_HERE],
                              c = new String[YOUR_VALUE_HERE],
                              d = new String[YOUR_VALUE_HERE];
private static final String[][] all = {a,b,c,d};
```

You can still initialize the contents of the arrays later, since only the array reference itself is final.

Comment: Also I gues you can use a `static` initializer block: static `{ /*init arrays here*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have static and final arrays, I suggest you to use singleton patten with only accessors. That way you have one instance (static) and those arrays can't be changed on another (final).

```
public class ArrayContainer {
    private ArrayContainer instance = new ArrayContainer();
    private static final int SIZE_A = 1;
    private static final int SIZE_B = 2;
    private static final int SIZE_C = 3;
    private static final int SIZE_D = 4;
    private static String[] a, b, c, d;
    private static String[][] all;

    private ArrayContainer() {
        a = new String[SIZE_A];
        b = new String[SIZE_B];
        c = new String[SIZE_C];
        d = new String[SIZE_D];
        all = new String[][]{a, b, c, d};
    }

    public String[] getA(){
        return a;
    }

    public String[] getB(){
        return b;
    }

    public String[] getC(){
        return c;
    }

    public String[] getD(){
        return d;
    }

    public String[][] getAll(){
        return all;
    }
}
```

Anyway you should remember that final array is not immutable. If you would like to have immutable I suggest you read this: [Immutable array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java).

Still you can also add only getters like

```
public String get(int array, int index){
    return all[i][y];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to init your static fields, use static block:

```
static final String[] a;
static {
    // put all the logic here
    // and assign final var at the end
    a = new String[17];
}
static final String[][] all = {a};
```

Remember also, that order in example above is important. Declaration of `all` array before initialization of `a` would cause `The blank final field a may not have been initialized` error.