# How to fill an array with random immutable values?

Tags: java, arrays

```
private void create(){
    byte[] arr = new byte[20];
    new Random().nextBytes(arr);
}
```

Allways generate random values.

How to create immutable random values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immutable array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700971/immutable-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a seed value in order to return the same set of bytes.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] arr = new byte[20];

        // Generating a random seed for demo. You can assign a fixed value e.g. 1 to seed.
        int seed = new Random().nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Going to print the byte array 10 times for the seed " + seed);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            create(arr, seed);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }

    private static void create(byte[] arr, int seed) {
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        random.nextBytes(arr);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Going to print the byte array 10 times for the seed -932843232
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
[74, 4, -46, -54, 49, 14, 32, -61, 20, -5, 1, 49, -64, -98, 68, 2, -74, 56, 28, -31]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have generated the random numbers in the array of bytes. If we want to make it immutable we can pack the generated byte array into unmodifiable list as shown below.

```
   private List<Integer> create(int capacity){
      byte[] arr = new byte[capacity];
      Random random = new Random();
      random.nextBytes(arr);
      List<Integer> randNumbers = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
      for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
        randNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[i]));
      }
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(randNumbers);
  }

  // Called with size 20
  List<Integer> immutableList = create(20);
```